# Node.js: decipher string that has been encrypted by openssl

Tags: node.js, encryption, openssl

In node.js I need to decipher a string that has been encrypted by `openssl` in linux bash like this:

```
$ printf 'bar' | openssl aes-256-ctr -a -pass pass:secret
U2FsdGVkX1/5Zhb07x8v0nw7jQ==
```

In node.js I try to decipher like this:

```
var decipher = crypto.createDecipher("aes-256-ctr", "secret");
var out = decipher.update("U2FsdGVkX1/5Zhb07x8v0nw7jQ==", 'hex', 'utf8');
out += decipher.final('utf8');
console.log(out); // => empty string
```

But all I get is an empty string.
Where am I doing wrong?

**edit:**
I'm still getting wrong result but in any case I realized that the encrypted string should be treated as `base64` instead of `hex` like this:

```
var out = decipher.update("U2FsdGVkX1/5Zhb07x8v0nw7jQ==", 'base64');
out += decipher.final('utf8');
```

Comment: OpenSSL uses an insecure KDF named `EVP_BytesToKey`.  Implementing this in NodeJS isn't worth your time since the KDF is no longer recommended for use anyway.  Do you have control over the OpenSSL command that is in use?

Comment: Yes I have control over OpenSSL. In the mean time I realized that anyway the ecrypted password should be treated as "base64", not "hex"

Comment: You should instead directly pass a key as hex using `-K`.